# Symfony2 embedded Type collection duplicate on update

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have many to many relationship with 2 Entities. For some reason on preupdate, doctrine adds new ids to child entities. All annotations are set up right along the entity types. So how can i prevent doctrine to set new ids on preupdate?

#### Edit:

Booking entity

```
/**
* Bookings
*
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\Entity\BookingRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*
*/
class Booking
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $guests
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="...\Entity\Guest", inversedBy="bookings", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Bookings_Guests",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="booking_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="guest_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 */
protected $guests;
```

Guest entity

```
/**
* Guests
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\Entity\GuestRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Guest
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $bookings
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="...\Entity\Booking", mappedBy="guests")
 */
protected $bookings;
```

Add new booking and delete work, its only when I add new guest to existing booking that doctrine assigns new id to that new guest. Before persisting to doctrine i've inspected `booking` object and its file, but when i debug it in `preupdate` listener, the new guest has new id (first available).

#### Edit 2:

Here is how my addGuests look like

```
public function addGuest(\Milos\RafailoviciBundle\Entity\Guest $guests)
{

//  $guests->addBooking($this);
    $this->guests[] = $guests;

//  if (!$this->guests->contains($guests)) {
//      $this->guests[] = $guests;
//      $guests->addBooking($this);
//  }
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see I've experimented a lot with addGuest as well.

I've just notices since the property is named in plural `guests` should I change the method to plural `addGuests`.

Any way here is the controller part:

```
public function editBookingAction(Request $request, Booking $booking){

    $form = $this->createForm(new BookingEditType(), $booking);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // even tried with $em->persist($booking); result is the same
        $em->flush();

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

I've even tried with `$id` instead of `$booking` being passed to action, result is the same.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What exactly preupdate are you talking about? What about providing the code you are working with?

Comment: What does your `addGuests` method look like in the Booking entity? Also, what does the code look like where you are persisting the entities? I've actually ran across a similar issue where duplicate entities were created due to the way I was calling `flush` and `clear` on the EntityManager in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with solution in case someone needs it:

I store all guest ids in array var and then I remove all guests from booking, flush and then get guests from repository with id and add them one by one to booking and flush. This way doctrine does not create duplicate guests.

```
    $ids = [];
    foreach($booking->getGuests() as $guest) {
        $ids[] = $guest->getId();
        $booking->getGuests()->removeElement($guest);
    }

    $this->em->flush();

    foreach($ids as $id) {
        $guest = $this->em->getRepository('MilosRafailoviciBundle:Guest')->find($id);
        $booking->addGuest($guest);
    }

    $this->em->flush();
```